# Center content in middle div between 2 divs

Tags: html, css, width, center

I have a header that has an element on the left and the right and an element in the middle whose width fills the space that is remaining in the middle.  I know the left and right elements width in px.  I need the content of the middle element in the centre of that remaining space, no matter how wide it is.

HTML

```
  <section class="header">
       <div class="left"></div>
       <div class="middle">
               <ul>
                  <li><button></button></li>
                  <li><button></button></li>
                  <li><button></button></li>
               </ul>
       </div>
       <button class="right"></button>  
  </section>
```

CSS:

```
.left {
    width:100px;
}

.middle {
    /*
     * This width is 100% of the space between left and right, 
     * content needs to be centered within it
     */
}

.right {
     width:100px;
}
```

Comment: Will the header occupy 100% of the window's width?

Comment: it can easely be done  adding & setting `.header { display:table} .header > * {display:table-cell}`

Comment: yes, it will be 100% width

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/uN6Rw/1/

Answer (score 0):

I tried the thing you asked in the question and i got a output which i am thinking is correct .

First I am adding the code which i modified little bit

HTML

```
<section class="header">
    <div class="left"><button>hai</button></div>
       <div class="middle">
               <ul>
                  <li><button></button></li>
                  <li><button></button></li>
                  <li><button></button></li>
               </ul>
       </div>
       <button class="right">right</button>  
  </section>
```

CSS

```
.left{
width: 100px;
float: left;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
left: 10px;
}

.header
{
    background:red;
}

.middle{
/*This width is 100% of the space between left and right, 
content needs to be centered within it*/
    position: relative;
left: 37%;
}

.right{
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

I am adding the link to jsfiddle where i implemented the needed

http://jsfiddle.net/pMdL7/1/

Comment: @user2415131 If this is the right answer then accept it ,else draw in a paint how you need the output and post the image of that